# How to drag and resize rubberband using mouse on Qlabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a rubber band on a `QLabel`. I want to drag and resize that rubber band using the mouse. Can anyone please help on this?

Below is my code:

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(mRubberBand->geometry().contains(event->pos()))
    {
       rubberband_offset = event->pos() - mRubberBand->pos();
       move_rubberband = true;
    }
 else
    {
       Origin= event->pos();
     //qDebug()<<Origin;

     // Move the rubber band to the new position
     // and set its size to 0x0
       mRubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(Origin, QSize()));
      // Display the rubber band
      mRubberBand->show();
    }
  }
}

  void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
// esize the rubber band rectangle
if(move_rubberband)
{
    mRubberBand->move(event->pos() - rubberband_offset);
}
else
{
mRubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(Origin, event->pos()).normalized());
// Display the size of the rectangle
QToolTip::showText( event->globalPos(), QString("%1,%2")
                                            .arg(mRubberBand->size().width())
                                            .arg(mRubberBand->size().height()),this );
//qDebug()<<Origin<<" "<<mRubberBand->size().width()<<","<<mRubberBand->size().height();
//qDebug()<<Origin.x()<<Origin.y();
 }

 }

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    EndPoint = event->pos();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Actually an answer but having not enough credit for comments.

Your code is bit broken. where do you set `move_rubberband` to `false` ?

So `mRubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(Origin, event->pos()).normalized());` will never be reached.

Ich guess you do it in the not pasted releaseEvent ?

Comment: i set move_rubberband to  false in main function .so it is not a problem for me ....

Comment: I can not see how you can be sure it it set to false. It is set to true in pressEvent and would nornally be set back in the releaseEvent ?!

Comment: Also it would be interesting what works as you expect and what does not work. Did you try spreading some qDebug() calls to which code is actually executed during the whole drag and drop action ?

Comment: hai......i am able to draw and drag that rubberband perfectly and my problem is how to resize it.i think you dont need my code ...just give idea by understanding above code

Comment: Looks not too bad. Albeit, it would be good to know what all those ´qDebug()´s tell you.